# Include index: [(A) include (B, C, D)] or [(A, B) include (C, D)]?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT BookID
FROM Books
WHERE IsArchived = 1 AND Rating > 60 AND CategoryID IN (1, 2, 3)
```

When I execute it in SQL Server 2012, the execution plan result tells me that

> Missing index: ...
>
> CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ON Books (IsArchived, Rating) INCLUDE (BookID, CategoryID)

My question is, should I create the index:

`(IsArchived) INCLUDE (Rating, BookID, CategoryID)`

or

`(IsArchived, Rating) INCLUDE (BookID, CategoryID)` according to the tips given

IMO, second way is less flexible due to restricted column orders (`[Rating]` follows `[IsArchived]`). Any suggestions are appreciated!

======= updated =======

I assume impact levels for columns ordered like this:

`[1: IsArchived]` > `[2: Rating]` > `[3: CategoryID]`

so is there much difference between [1 inlcude 2, 3] vs [1, 2 include 3] vs [1, 2, 3]

Comment: This entirely depends on the cardinality of `Rating > 60`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "second way is less flexible due to restricted orders"

Comment: for 2nd design, to make index valid on query, use of [Rating] must follows [IsArchived], this does not happen on 1st design @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: Unfortunately, only you actually have access to your tables, your data, *all* of your query access patterns, etc. Only you can actually experiment and determine whether the first index will actually satisfy the query processor or whether it will still spit out the message recommending the other index. It's rarely correct to try to design indexes, as you ask us to here, in the context of a *single* query. For that *single* query, you already know what the optimizer thinks would have been most helpful

Comment: To expand on @Damien_The_Unbeliever good advice - you also should consider your existing queries and existing indexes to see if some can be rewritten to use fewer indexes. Often you see multiple indexes which could be one just by rewriting a few queries or restructuring some data usage.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever TY. I tested both ways, they don't have much difference in execution time (100ms ~ 200ms for about 1M records table) and I can hardly say that one is definitely better than another...

Answer (score 1):

When designing Indexes, in your B_Tree. The Main Level you should have the joins, Where clauses and Order By. Then the Includes be your select statement.

Also you dont need to include the BookID if its your primary key only if you get a lookup. But this all depends on your execution plan on your server and the amount of data.

(IsArchived), (Rating), (CategoryID) Include (BookID)

Comment: TY. I know (IsArchived), (Rating), (CategoryID) Include (BookID) is the most suitable design for THE query I mentioned, however to make index more flexible for other queries, can I change it into (IsArchived) include (X, Y, Z), do they have same performance ? I tested both ways, they don't have much difference in execution time. @mvisser

Comment: Very good question.  So nonclustered index is sort order of how the data is stored. Include is only there for the lookup. Give an example for telephone directory.  If I search by name and have the include number. It will do a seek if your where clause is by name. Now if I do by numner, it will do an Index scan, it will better performance, than doing a Clustered index scan. But if you have millions of rows in the Index. It will be very slow.

Comment: So when I design Indexes. I try make it so that the if I have joins, wheres or Order By that will be my main level.  The problem is if I have a where clause where rating = 2 and Order By IsArchived DESC.  And my Index is IsArchived ASC.  That will also make your index slow. So If do an Index for a application.  I remove any order by and do it in the code

Comment: Also consider using Partial Indexes. If this Index is going to be used often.  I mean often, like I had a SP that was executed over 1000 times a second.  So I know that the Index needs to be the best performance that it can be.

Comment: But also to remember. That you need to include the Primary Key(BookID) if thats your primary Key. it will be explicitly included.

Answer (score 1):

These sorts of index tuning are more of an art form than having an exact answer.

The way I would look at this is that you're actually searching the data based upon three columns

1. IsArchived
2. Rating
3. CategoryID

You're then using one field in the SELECT statement;

- BookID

From this, you know that you're definitely going to want `BookID` in the includes, but you need to work out what's going to be the best for you with regards to the other three fields.

Which of these fields is going to help you reduce the data the most? Say you have 1,000,000 rows of data, how many of them have `IsArchived = 1`? How many have `Rating > 60` (and is this field an int?)? How many have a `CategoryID IN (1,2,3)`?

For these three, you want to be reducing your data as much as possible as soon as possible. Consider which of these would have the greatest impact on your data volume and use this one first. Then the next most relevant, then the last one.

The order will have less impact as you go further into your clustered fields so you definitely want the field with most impact first.

**Edit:**

As per your edit, only you are going to know which of these is going to be best with the data you have. As somebody without this information I'd probably go with

```
INDEX (1,2,3) INCLUDE (BookID)
```

Which would give you the most sorted data for *this particular query*. You could always implement a couple if you're testing, update the statistics, then test which is best for your example. The optimiser will use the best one and you can check the `actual execution plan` to see which index it is using.

Comment: I assume impact levels for columns ordered like this: [1: IsArchived] > [2: Rating] > [3: CategoryID], so is there much difference between [1 inlcude 2, 3] vs [1, 2 include 3] vs [1, 2, 3] ? @RichBenner

Comment: You're going to see diminishing returns as you add more into the indexed columns so the impact of 3 won't be as much as 2, which won't have the impact of 1. In this example I'd still put it in as an indexed field as you're using it as a predicate. Your included fields aren't sorted at all so if you're using any calculation on them then you'd want to check whether indexing (ordering) them is what you need to do.

Comment: Do you have CategoryID as a index its self? If so then you can include it in the INCLUDE. Otherwise you will need to put in the Main Level.

Comment: @mvisser could you explain this further? Maybe link to some documentation that would suggest that this would be a good idea? Genuinely interested.

Comment: So when designing indexes. You design based on OLTP and OLAP architectures. Most database use the both designs on the same database. Because its to expensive for warehousing. SO you know when creating indexes on OLTP method. You create all indexes on your Foreign Keys. CategoryID seems to be a Foreign Key(I dont know). So I would suggest to put it in the include. Why becuase for every CRUD statement it will have to do it in the Foreign Key Index and the one we just created. Causing a huge performance issue.